# ClassNotFoundException when running a class from a jar but if I run the class directly in my application it works

Tags: java, maven, junit, jar, classpath

I wanted to add a section into our `application` which allows users to upload a `jar` containing `JUnit` tests.  I want to be able to run these `jar`'s tests within my `java application`.  I can get the `Class` to be loaded from the `Jar` but when it goes to run the test it will fail with an error `ClassNotFoundException` for a required library.  If I put the same `Class` in my application and run it, it works fine.  I am loading all the libraries through maven.

When running:

```
Result result = junit.run(c.getClass());
                for (Failure failure : result.getFailures()) {
                    Logger.info("Failure: " + failure.toString());
                }
```

Output: (see below for detailed stack trace)

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openqa.selenium.Capabilities
```

## Problem

If I run the same test with putting the `Test` `class` within the `classpath` and call it via the class directly it works correctly and runs the test within `Appium`

```
JUnitCore junit = new JUnitCore();
Result result = junit.run(Test.class);
```

When I go to load the same `class` from the `jar` it fails.

## Question

Does anyone know why this would be happening?

When running the `jar will it use the libraries loaded by the application or do I need to package the required libraries into the jar/directly on the classpath loader?

Maven is setup to import all the `Selenium`/`Appium` `jar`s correctly.  If I run the test directly within my application there is no issue just when the class is taken from the jar.

```
 import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
```

Should I add the `Selenium/Appium` `jar` directly on my `classloader`?

```
URL[] classLoaderUrls = new URL[]{new URL("file:///c:/Work 2016/simpleappiumtest2.jar"), new URL("file:///c:/Work 2016/libraries/Selenium/selenium-server-standalone-2.53.0.jar")};
```

I can not get that to run when I do that.

## Update here is another way I can run the code and it also fails.

```
        try {
        // Getting the jar URL which contains target class
        URL[] classLoaderUrls = new URL[]{new URL("file:///c:/Work 2016/simpleappiumtest2.jar")};
        //Code to run junit test
        URLClassLoader urlClassLoader = new URLClassLoader(classLoaderUrls);
         // Load the target class
        Class<?> appiumClass = urlClassLoader.loadClass("simpleapp.simpleappium");
        // Run the class using JUnitCore
        JUnitCore junit = new JUnitCore();
        Result result = junit.run(appiumClass);
        //Display if test was successful
        Logger.info(result.wasSuccessful());

        Logger.info("Tests run: " + result.getRunCount());
        Logger.info("Tests failed: " + result.getFailureCount());
        for (Failure failure : result.getFailures()) {
            Logger.info("Failure: " + failure.toString());
            Logger.info("Failure desc: " + failure.getDescription());
            Logger.info("Failure excp: " + failure.getException());
            Logger.info("Failure trace: " + failure.getTrace());
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

## Code

```
   // not on class path File jarLocation = new File("C:/Work/testcases-0.0.1.jar");
   File jarLocation = new File("lib/testcases-0.0.1.jar");  // on classpath

    try {

        JarInputStream testJarFile;
        testJarFile = new JarInputStream(new FileInputStream(jarLocation));

        while (true) {
            JarEntry testJar = testJarFile.getNextJarEntry();
            if (testJar == null) {
              break;
            }
            if ((testJar.getName().endsWith(".class"))) {

                String file = testJar.getName();
                String classname = file.replace('/', '.').substring(0, file.length() - 6);
                try 
                {
                    Class<?> c = Class.forName(classname);


                    JUnitCore junit = new JUnitCore();
                    Result result = junit.run(c.getClass());
                    for (Failure failure : result.getFailures()) {

                Logger.info("Failure: " + failure.toString());
                Logger.info("Failure desc: " + failure.getDescription());
                Logger.info("Failure excp: " + failure.getException());
                Logger.info("Failure trace: " + failure.getTrace());
                    }

                }
                catch (Throwable e) 
                {
                    Logger.error("WARNING: failed to instantiate " + classname + " from " + file);
                    Logger.error("ERROR: Exception " + e);
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

## Test Class

```
  public class Test {

      @Test
      public void test() throws MalformedURLException {

          //Grab file - device info
          File appDir = new File("lib");
          File app = new File(appDir, "deviceinfo.apk");

          //Setup as android device
          DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
          cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, MobilePlatform.ANDROID);
          cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "Android Device");

          //Run app
          cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.NEW_COMMAND_TIMEOUT, "20");  //only wait 20 sec
          cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP, app.getAbsolutePath());
          AndroidDriver driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), cap);

          //Close app
          driver.closeApp();
      }
  }
```

## Stack Trace

```
2016-05-26 09:11:49 [http-nio-8082-exec-1] INFO  com.miw.mcb.server.MCBLogger - ::::: MCBLogger ::::: Failure: initializationError(com.miw.mcb.testcases.AndroidTest): org/openqa/selenium/Capabilities
2016-05-26 09:11:49 [http-nio-8082-exec-1] INFO  com.miw.mcb.server.MCBLogger - ::::: MCBLogger ::::: Failure desc: initializationError(com.miw.mcb.testcases.AndroidTest)
2016-05-26 09:11:49 [http-nio-8082-exec-1] INFO  com.miw.mcb.server.MCBLogger - ::::: MCBLogger ::::: Failure excp: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/Capabilities
2016-05-26 09:11:49 [http-nio-8082-exec-1] INFO  com.miw.mcb.server.MCBLogger - ::::: MCBLogger ::::: Failure trace: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/Capabilities
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
        at org.junit.internal.builders.SuiteMethodBuilder.hasSuiteMethod(SuiteMethodBuilder.java:18)
        at org.junit.internal.builders.SuiteMethodBuilder.runnerForClass(SuiteMethodBuilder.java:10)
        at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
        at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
        at org.junit.runner.Computer.getRunner(Computer.java:40)
        at org.junit.runner.Computer$1.runnerForClass(Computer.java:31)
        at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
        at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.runners(RunnerBuilder.java:101)
        at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.runners(RunnerBuilder.java:87)
        at org.junit.runners.Suite.<init>(Suite.java:81)
        at org.junit.runner.Computer.getSuite(Computer.java:28)
        at org.junit.runner.Request.classes(Request.java:75)
        at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:105)
        at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:94)
        at com.miw.mcb.adbservice.controller.HomeController.runAppiumTest(HomeController.java:511)
        at com.miw.mcb.adbservice.controller.HomeController.runTestRunOnDevice(HomeController.java:268)
        at com.miw.mcb.adbservice.controller.HomeController.runTest(HomeController.java:162)
        at com.miw.mcb.adbservice.controller.HomeController.runTestRun(HomeController.java:128)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:817)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:731)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:968)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:870)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:844)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:87)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:121)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:522)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1095)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openqa.selenium.Capabilities
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at java.net.FactoryURLClassLoader.loadClass(URLClassLoader.java:814)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 76 more
```

**POM**

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>4.12</version>
</dependency>

<!-- add appium dependencies -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
  <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
  <version>3.4.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.zeroturnaround</groupId>
  <artifactId>zt-process-killer</artifactId>
  <version>1.4</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
    <version>4.5.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
    <artifactId>plexus-utils</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.24</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
  <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
  <version>2.53.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-remote-driver</artifactId>
    <version>2.53.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-android-driver</artifactId>
    <version>2.39.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: You'd need your jar in the classpath

Comment: @UUID                   Which classpath?  Of the loader or the application?  The jar is in the classpath of the application.

If I run the Class directly from my application it works fine.  When I run the class within the jar it fails.   Check the code I added an update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current classpath needs to be loaded to allow access to the libraries loaded by the application

```
URLClassLoader cl = new URLClassLoader(classLoaderUrls, getClass().getClassLoader());
```